# Wrong Data, Wrong Direction, Career suicide

Tags: phd, advisor, supervision

I am on a very weird situation once again. Being doing my phd in Europe since 2020. The field is computational multi-omics. I had a nice supervisor to work on a very interesting topic. After analysing data provided from my supervisor for a year, had a draft of my paper, we realised that the data we worked was an intermediate version of the final release. I was more into "together we rise, together we fall" mode and I just accepted waiting 4 months for the new data, and 6 more months to rerun the major analysis. It took me 8 more months to run additional analyses, building on top of the major analysis.

In the meantime, he publishes at least 7 papers, some of them on a very similar subject I am working on without helping his students getting extra publications. I don't blame him for that, but at the moment I don't have a single one.

Recently I realised an incredible simplistic mistake, where during the first months, I was benchmarking different methods for the input data, comparing them and delivered everything to my supervisor for discussion. Unfortunately, he made the wrong decision.

And now I am f****d up. Twice.

So I am starting over. I wish I would have done my own mistakes to blame.

Just not be sure how to move on, in terms of having a person guiding me who is incapable to keep track of things. Even last month, I gave him an abstract to check for submission into a conference, and he changed so many things, where in the end he mixed up everything that I couldn't understand what is happening in the project. So he clearly does not have a clue which analysis was performed on what, BUT I have a huge workflow chart in pdf, where everything is explained till the software, libraries and environments details.

It is too late to change department or PI now.

What shall I do? My stress levels are hitting red, every time I interact with him it's just a misery. As soon as I work alone, my mood is really good and I enjoy what I am doing.

I have tried to communicate issues with my committee members, and they showed clearly not interested getting on top of the situation.

Comment: I don't think your post is very clear, it takes several turns, and "what should I do?" isn't a very answerable thing to ask. What's the specific issue that you think people familiar with academia that are not directly working with you on research can help you with?

Comment: I've shared my situation because there seems to be an 'omertà' around discussing such matters within my institute and university. I need to determine whether my advisor is hindering my career. Should I accept it and pursue another path, even though I am passionate about what I am doing?

Comment: How can we help with that?

Comment: By sharing your experience, I guess. Is there a way out? Should I just drop out now, considering my academic career may be finished? Have you ever worked with a person you don't trust? How do you handle it? That was my intention; I am sure this has happened to another person, maybe not yourself.

Comment: I mean how do we know if your advisor is hindering your career? Some of the things you describe don't seem like their fault at all. Are you blaming them for it? Why? If you are doing benchmarking, what is your advisor making a decision about and what would make it wrong?

Comment: I will not get into details to secure the anonymity of the post, but if he did not know which method is correct or wrong, he should have let me choose what I consider the right one, rather than pushing me to take a particular path from an analysis perspective. He even acknowledged that it was his mistake to suggest the particular method.

Comment: From what you write, it seems to me that your trainer is abusing you, or even robbing you. So it will be best to change the trainer and, in this case, maybe even the whole workplace.

Comment: @blaha I don't find your post so incomprehensible. I would only depersonalize and generalize it. That means it wants to eliminate the sighs of screams and questions like "What should I do?". For some reason, some communities don't like personalized content, even though that content can provide an answer to others.

Comment: I am not sure what you should do, but your academic career is definitely not finished. I restarted my phd after having a very bad experience, now I am close to finish with quite a few publications, with a very good supervisor. Indeed, I so much enjoy it, I do not really want to finish :)
I felt very similarly when I stopped the previous one, as everything is over. It is not!

Comment: thank you @juandev and aqua for your answers :)